# Baseball Autographs

Tags: baseball

Is the any place that you can scan an autograph to a data base to find out what player you have. I have been left multiple signed baseballs but have no idea who they are.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to take them to a reputable collector or store that deals with memorabilia. They'd likely either be able to tell you right away or at least be able to compare them to other valuable signatures to make sure that it's nothing extremely valuable or rare.